# Restful API Design for Heterogenous objects

Tags: api, rest, api-design

Im building a rest API that serves up data from a set of complicated documents. Theres about 150 different document types, each with their own specific sections and data requirements determined by gov't regulations.

I have a list endpoint that looks a bit like:

`GET /v1/filings/`

This returns a `list` of objects that look roughly like this:

```
{
    status: int 
    filings: [{ filing_id: str, 
                filing_type: str, 
                filingDate: str
                ...
               }, ... {}]
}
```

You can grab a filing by it's `filing_id` and pass it to another `get` endpoint.

`GET /v1/filings/<filing_id>`

This return a blob of the raw file data.

```
{ 
    status: int
    filing_id: str
    file_text: str
}
```

**Here's the rub**: I want to create an endpoint to get certain sections of a document.
Something along the lines of:

`GET /v1/filings/<filing_id>/Section4`

The problem with this is there are hundreds of different possible document types each with fairly different section types, so a user could potentially request a filing_id of a file with a non supported format for that endpoint.

Im trying to decide if it's better to do checking in each endpoint for a valid ID for that specific extension, or if I should make a set of endpoints for the specific filing type:

```
GET /v1/filings/

GET /v1/filing_type_1/<filing_id>/Section_id_specific_to_filing_type_1

GET /v1/filing_type_2/<filing_id>/Section_id_specific_to_filing_type_2
```

So here's the question:

Which approach is better//more RESTful? Having a generic interface (e.g. `GET /v1/filing/<id>/SectionIdentifier`) that returns errors when users request a section identifier for a filing id that isnt supported?

Or to create an endpoint path for each filing type, and leave it up to the users to call the right ones?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    status: int 
    filings: [{ filing_id: str, 
                filing_type: str, 
                filingDate: str
                ...
               }, ... {}]
}
```

Heuristic: how would you do it with a web page?

The web page would probably have a list of filings, with each filing described by fields similar to the ones you have here, and a [link](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8288) to follow to get to the resource associated with a specific filing.

Represented this way, the client doesn't need to know how to guess the URI spelling, they just need to know how to find the link that they want.  They then follow that link to make progress.

That gives you the freedom to choose whatever spelling conventions for your identifiers that make your life easier.

When you want to publish links to specific sections of the document, you use the same pattern: you define a link relation for each section, and for those filings that have a Section_id_specific_to_filing_type_2 resource, you include the appropriate link relation.

Note: assuming you aren't going to go through the work of [registering](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8288#section-2.1.1.1) a standard link relation, then your relation names should follow the spelling conventions of an [extended relation type](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8288#section-2.1.2) - in other words, your custom relation names should be URI.

Of course, if there is already a [registered relation](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) that matches your needs, then you should use it, rather than rolling your own.